# C++ return object member variable when object is called?

Tags: c++, class, object

How do you make a class for example return a member variable when it is called? Say:

```
class Person {
    std::string name;

    // Constructor and Destructor go here..
};

Person mike = "Mike";

// /!\ How do you make "mike" return "Mike" directly when the object mike is called?
//  This is the same thing like an int return its value and a vector returns its members (scalars)
std::string name = mike;
```

Additional Edit: The cast operator is not a good option here as it ruins the way a type is written. For example `std::string name = static_cast<string>(mike);` is a horrible way to achieve my target.

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for the ["cast operator"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator)?

Comment: @0x5453 is there not something like "__repr__" in Python? I'm no expert in Python but I think this method implements what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Python and C++ are two different languages.  C++ has its own set of paradigms, idioms, and rules.

Comment: @xxdraxulis You can always overload `to_string(const Person&)` or `operator<<(std::ostream&, const Person&)`, but those don't behave quite like Python's `__repr__`.

Comment: consider that implicit conversion come at a (not so obvious) price. Suddenly you will not get compiler errors for using a `Person` where a `std::string` is required. Is the converision intended or is it a logic error? Now its up to you, no more help from the compiler on that

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Of course they aren't. I'm just asking for the equivalent.

Comment: @0x5453 That's right. I've overloaded the `operator<<(std::ostream&, const Person&) and it works for streams only as the name suggests.

Comment: Advice -- Do not use another language as a model in writing C++ code.  All you'll end up with are programs that are buggy, inefficient, or just plain weird looking to a C++ programmer.

Comment: @idclev463035818 You're right. But I have assertions all over the place to make sure these compile time and run time errors don't happen.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie That's correct. I thought I did not explain my target correctly so I tried giving an example in another language that I know of. Bad thing to say.

Comment: @xxdraxulis -- ok.  No harm.  It's just that there are so many questions here where the poster is actually trying to use another language's way of doing things in C++.

Comment: what i tried to say is that not getting the compiler errors is the drawback. Suppose you have a function `foo(std::string logmessage)` and you don't want to pass a `Person` because it is not a `logmessage`, with implicit conversion the compiler cannot "find" such bugs for you

Comment: @idclev463035818 That is especially true, but only when you're making a program consisting of code that works together; my code works on top of each other, if you know what I mean. This functionality is necessary and a little less prone to becoming buggy as it is never used by myself, just by the program, which itself checks the types of such things before passing them. My point might've gotten a little abstract, but this functionality is rather essential for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for a conversion operator, which is written like this:

```
class Person {
    std::string name;
 public:
    Person(char const * name) : name(name) {}
    operator std::string () const { return name; }
};
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/j647Tf).

You could also make the conversion operator a template, like this:

```
template<typename T>
operator T() const { return name; }
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/PvscYz).

Comment: If it doesn't need the `static_cast<>();` operator then this answered my question. Now do you know how to make this work as a template? My class is template so I don't want to explicitly implement this function for every type. Thanks.

Comment: @xxdraxulis Sure, you can template it, added to the answer.

Comment: Far from relevant but note that `Person(char const * name) : name(name) {}` is UB if `name` is `nullptr`. Why `std::string` doesn't construct empty in that situation is beyond me.

Comment: `Person(char const * name) : name(name?name:"") {}`